# How to track Solr Keywords when used in a search using Coldfusion 10

Tags: solr, coldfusion, cfsearch

I'm currently using cf 10 and making alot of use using cfsearch (solr) and I'm just wondering if there is a way to report / record what people are searching for on my website.

I have read that this is possible when using solr directly on other platforms... So I'm hoping there is an easy way to retrieve this via a cf tag

Any ideas greatly appreciated.

Comment: That's quite a misleading question title, innit?

Comment: Assuming you control the form that is used to submit the search parameters, you can simply grab the contents of the search field(s) (before or after you have completed your search) and store that information however you see fit.

Comment: I'd make than an "Answer", @ScottStroz. It's a fairly vague answer, but it matches the vagueness of the question, and is - accordingly - completely fitting.

Comment: Expanding on @ScottStroz's comment, it doesn't have to be before or after.  With cfthread it can be at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you control the form that is used to submit the search parameters, you can simply grab the contents of the search field(s) (before or after you have completed your search - or as Dan pointed out, you could spin that process off into a `cfthread` to be done concurrently) and store that information however you see fit.